# How to handle numbers greater than Double.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, floating-point, numbers, double

I am continuously adding a stream of numbers and calculating their average in JAVA.
However the maximum value of average that I can store is Double.MAX_VALUE i.e 1.7976931348623157E308 after which the value becomes INFINITY.
How can I store values beyond the Double.MAX_VALUE in JAVA?

Comment: Look into `BigDecimal` class.

Comment: Overflowing with a sum? Waouh, it's rather rare! I'm curious how you came to such huge value? What is the distribution of values in the stream?

Comment: Double.MAX_VALUE is a **very** large number. The overflow is more likely to be due to a bug than to adding correct but large values.

Comment: In general, how to handle a case in which the value of a double variable exceeds its limit?

Answer (score 2):

You may use java.math.BigDecimal class.